# embedding ruby in javascript ".click" method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following javascript reveals hidden view code when "View Conversation" is clicked. When "View Conversation" is clicked and the conversation revealed, I want to update the state of the last message in the conversation from "unread" to "read". I'm having trouble embedding this Ruby code to trigger on click, though. As a test, I was able to get a javascript alert to pop up on clicking "View Conversation," so I believe this is the right place to insert my code for updating the last message's state. However, I'm not getting results consistent with what I see in the test alert message. Would appreciate any input! Thanks.

```
$('#inbox .btn-view-conversation').toggle(function(){
    $(this).text('Hide Conversation');
    $(this).parents('.row-message').find('.message-conversation').slideDown();

    // alert('message!') triggers on click correctly
    $(this).click(alert('message!'));

    // the code below sometimes triggers when the page loads (before click), 
    // but sometimes not at all. 
    $(this).click('<% Message.last.update_attributes(:state => 'read') %>')

    return false;
  }, function(){
    $(this).text('View Conversation');
    $(this).parents('.row-message').find('.message-conversation').slideUp();
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: javascript run on client side while ruby run on server side, what you need to do is to use post or get to access your server code through javascript

Comment: You're trying to execute ruby code in a `click` JS method? You need some kind of ajax request to that. Here, the code `Message.last.update_attributes(:state => 'read')` executes once when the page renders, and that's it

Comment: i thought it may have had to do with a server/client-side issue. should i use get in my javascript to access my ruby code?

Comment: This does not look like plain Javascript. It looks like jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Ajax to trigger Ruby code from Javascript. You can't "embed" Ruby code in Javascript.
You need to understand the difference between a client-side script and a server-side script.

For example read: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080529114633AAHE4DE

After you understand this concepts the solution should be apparent.

Comment: Please go away and don't confuse newbies. Erb just outputs static Javascript, a browser can't execute Ruby, it's always executed on the server and that's why you need Ajax.

Comment: I understand the difference between client and server side scripts, but that doesn't make the solution self-evident. Does using Ajax to trigger Ruby code from Javascript technically not involve embedding Ruby code in Javascript with the necessary Ajax (If one can't "embed" Ruby code in Javascript, what is "js.erb"? I don't think you're correct here.)? The question is what Ajax to include and where.

Comment: .js.erb is a preprocessor. It takes the file whatever.js.erb, it finds Ruby code in that file, evaluates it, and writes the result into whatever.js, which is sent to the client as a static file. Ruby doesn't care if it's .js.erb or .potato.erb. Call it whatever you want but the browser doesn't have the capabilities to execute Ruby code. You didn't embed any Ruby code so that the browser could run it you just preprocessed a text file with Erb.
And the Ajax you need is so basic I won't even go there, you can figure that out by yourself. You do all the Ajax part in JS with no Ruby.